# D3js compatibility error with google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, word-cloud

I have this d3js script that should create a word cloud. 
Everything works fine on Firefox, but it seems on Google Chrome something is not working. I think the problem is here:

> attr("transform","translate("+size_width/2+",200)")

```
var div = document.getElementById("container");

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_cloud");

size_height = div.offsetHeight;

size_width  = div.offsetWidth;

console.log(size_width);

function wordCloud(selector) {

    var fill = d3.scale.category20();

    //Construct the word cloud's SVG element

    var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
        .attr("width", size_width)
        .attr("height", 400)
        .attr("transform","translate("+size_width/2+",200)")


    //Draw the word cloud
    function draw(words) {
        var cloud = svg.selectAll("text")
                        .data(words, function(d) { return d.text; })

        //Entering words
        cloud.enter()
            .append("a")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return d.url;})
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .append("text")
            .style("font-family", "Impact")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
            .attr("class","hover-item")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr('font-size', 1)
            .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
            .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })

        //Entering and existing words
        cloud
            .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

        //Exiting words
        // cloud.exit()
        //     .transition()
        //         .duration(200)
        //         .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
        //         .attr('font-size', 1)
        //         .remove();
    }


    //Use the module pattern to encapsulate the visualisation code. We'll
    // expose only the parts that need to be public.
    return {

        //Recompute the word cloud for a new set of words. This method will
        // asycnhronously call draw when the layout has been computed.
        //The outside world will need to call this function, so make it part
        // of the wordCloud return value.
        update: function(words) {
            d3.layout.cloud().size([size_width, 300])
                .words(words)
                .padding(5)
                .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 5; })
                .font("Impact")
                .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
                .on("end", draw)
                .start();
        }
    }

}

//This method tells the word cloud to redraw with a new set of words.
//In reality the new words would probably come from a server request,
// user input or some other source.
function showNewWords(vis, i) {
    i = i || 0;

    vis.update(words)
}

//Create a new instance of the word cloud visualisation.

  {% load jsonify %}

  var items = '{{ destinations|jsonify }}';
  items = JSON.parse(items);
setTimeout(function(){
    words = items;
    //words.push({ "text":'{{item.name}}',"size":{{item.importance}},"url":'destino-{{item.name}}' });
  var myWordCloud = wordCloud('.canv');
  showNewWords(myWordCloud);
}, 900);
```

Comment: try putting brackets in : (size_width/2)

Comment: is not an error .. the cloud is not displayed corectly.. smaller and uglier

Comment: do you have a working example ? On jsfiddle for example, or even 2 images to compare outputs ...

Comment: any idea on how can i make it work ?

Comment: @RobertLongson can you elaborate on chrome not supporting transform on an svg element ? Im sure ive used it multiple times and it works

Comment: @thisOneGuy I mean on an `<svg>` element in particular, Chrome supports it most other placed e.g `<g>` or graphics elements etc. It's a new feature in SVG2 to support it on an `<svg>` element.

Comment: @RobertLongson ..you're a genius . Add it as a answer and i will accept it. I added a <g> and i gave the transform method to the <g> element and now everything works perfect. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SVG 1.1 many elements do support the transform attribute but the `<svg>` element does not.

The ability to set a transform on an `<svg>` element is new in the as-yet-unfinished SVG 2 specification. Firefox has implemented that part of SVG 2 but Chrome has not yet done so.

You could create a child `<g>` element and put the transform on that as a workaround.

Comment: That is where I got confused. I normally append a <g> tag to my svg elements so in reality I am transforming the <g> element not the <svg>. Nice point